# GCP dataproc service account not_found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, service-accounts

When creating a Dataproc cluster I have the following error message:

> ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) NOT_FOUND: Service Account not found: '[PROJECT_NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

Same error when create from console or from `gcloud` CLI command. Anyone can help please? Many thanks.

Comment: Did you enable the Compute Engine API? GCP Console -> APIs & Services -> API Library -> Search for "Compute Engine API". If this is enabled, go to IAM & admin ->   IAM. Is this service account there?

Comment: Compute engine API is enabled. This service account doesn't exist. Can I change default service account? Maybe this will solve the problem

Comment: My second question?

Comment: '[PROJECT_NUMBER]-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com' doesn't exist in IAM / service account

Comment: Provided that you do not have any Compute Engine instances, disable the API what a few minutes and then reenable it. This will recreate the service account.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley), this issue is being generated as Dataproc requires to use the **Compute engine API** [default service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#compute_engine_default_service_account) to create the cluster instances; however, if this account is not longer displayed within your IAM > Service Account console, it will be required to [disable](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable#disabling) and [enable](https://cloud.google.com/service-usage/docs/enable-disable#enabling) the Compute Engine API in order to try to recreate it; otherwise, you can create a new project to recreate your environment.

On the other hand, in case you want to use a different service account for your Dataproc cluster, you can [create a new service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating_a_service_account) and [grant](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource) it with the required [GCE](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#compute-engine-roles) and [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#dataproc-roles) roles; in this way, you can specify the service account name to use when [creating your cluster](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create).

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create <CLUSTER_NAME> --service-account=<SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME>
```

Comment: I have stopped all compute engine, and required to disable compute engine API, I get an error message "Could not turn off service, as it still has resources in use.:[compute.googleapis.com]"  What else I should stop other than VMs before disabling Compute Engine API?

Comment: Is this an alternative option please  "gcloud beta app repair --project <your project id>"

Comment: You are getting this error message as you still have resources that require to have the GCE API enabled. I just made some test and I could disable the API until the VMs and the resources under the GCE section were deleted. Based on this, I recommend you to first try to create a new service account with the proper roles and verify if you can create the Dataproc cluster correctly, as well as take a look on the [Snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-snapshots) documentation to have a back up of your data.

Comment: Regarding the `gcloud beta app repair` command, it is seems  that it is related to restore of App Engine features not GCE, as mentioned in the [Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/app/repair) documentation.

Comment: ok thanks, I have disabled API for compute engine, waited few minutes and then enabled API. this is fine. I can not create compute engine but I have to define service account in CE creation screen. However, I cannot create dataproc from console, I have an error message, Service Account not found: 'does_not_exist@invalid-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

Comment: Once you disable and re-enable the API, the default service account should be re-created; however, it is seems that this didn't happen. I recommend you to create a bug by using the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187161&template=1162660) tool to follow-up this scenario with the GCP support team and verify if this is related to a configuration matter within your project.